# Is there an option to make component totally isolated so it doesn't trigger change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a clock on page and it is refreshed every second using `setInterval()` because of that all bindings of application are being checked. Is there an option in angular to put component in some kind of bubble so the clock on the page will be refreshed every second and it won't trigger change detection in other components?

I know that there is `NgZone` class with its `runOutsideAngular()` method but a far as i know it only isolates code inside *.ts files and not the templates.

Example of code:

**clock.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clock',
  templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentLocalTime: Date;

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentLocalTime = new Date();
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**clock.component.html**

```
<p>
  currentLocalTime 
</p>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-clock></app-clock>
.
.
.
.
<app-another></app-another>
```

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested? Does it solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you user `timer observable`. See a demo [HERE](https://angular-timer-observable.stackblitz.io). This should solve your problem.

Just create a timer observable as

```
time: number;
obsTimer:Observable<number> = timer(1000,1000);
```

and subscribe to it in `ngOnInit`

```
this.obsTimer.subscribe(time => this.time = time);
//here you can add milliseconds to your datetime object
```

As you see in the stackblitz snippet. the `console.log` method is not being called on `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnPush` change detection strategy which means change detectors triggered only if `@Input` property changes. You can change strategies like this:

```
@Component({
  ........
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

If you want to manually trigger change detector, you can inject `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

someMethod = () => {
    // do some changes
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

---

References:

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Answer (score 0):

You can detach `ChangeDetector` inside your component and trigger change detection manually. This gives you full control on checks. In your situation this approach will be more efficient than changing `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `push`.

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cdRef.detach();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentLocalTime = new Date();
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);

}
```